Go to definition in specflow feature file is not working in VS 2022
Go to definition in specflow feature file is not working in VS 2022.
New steps (definition less) are not coming in purple, all the steps are white coloured.
Trying to create definition for new steps is resulting in a dialog box with text "All steps have been defined in this file already" from visual studio extension for specflow

I built the solution
I closed and opened the VS
I uninstalled and installed specflow for visual studio 2022
I uninstalled and installed VS


Try closing all Visual Studio windows and then deleting the .vs folder at the root directory of the solution. The .vs folder contains transient cached data for Visual Studio. Lots of Visual Studio "weirdness" can be solved by deleting that folder and the rebuilding the solution.

I've encountered this issue as well. By chance, I deleted the previous StepDefinitions.cs file and then rebuilt the entire project, which resolved the issue.
I also tried many times. Sometimes simply rebuilding the project works, while other times I need to delete the previous StepDefinitions.cs file
My suggestion is to back up your previous StepDefinitions.cs files, then delete all of them, rebuild the project, and restore them afterwards. This might temporarily fix the issue.
